# How to make my Android app appear in the app chooser when clicking an email link in a WhatApp chat

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-manifest, manifest

I'm building an Android app that I want to appear in the app chooser when clicking an email address in a WhatsApp chat.

I tried various intent filters and even tried to change my app id in the gradle file since I read here that WhatsApp whitelists some apps, but none of this solution worked.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/>
            <data android:scheme="mailto"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <data android:scheme="mailto"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

```
applicationId "com.google.android.gm.test"
```

I expect that when I click an email address sent to me in a WhatsApp my app will appear in the app chooser, but it doesn't.

Does anyone have any input?

Comment: Please don't tag questions with IDE tags (android-studio) just because you use that IDE: these tags should only be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags), and the [tagging guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). Also, please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I just copy pasted your intent filters in my sample code and I am able to see my app appear in the chooser after clicking on an email on WhatsApp!!